# How drop down-list selected value assign to <small>

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to know how drop-down-list selected value assign to

Tried HTML code:

```
<h3>
  {{{titles}}}
  <small id="sec_currency">({{{subtitles}}})</small>
</h3>

<select id="cur_rate" @change="onChange()">
    {{#each currencies}}
      <option selected>{{this.currency}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Vue.js

```
onChange: function() {
  $('#sec_currency').val($('#cur_rate :selected').text());
}
```

When I tried the above code I am getting below error.

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this using the below-mentioned code.

```
$('#sec_currency').text($('#cur_rate :selected').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.text()` function is a getter function that returns the value of the text, so you cannot assign a value to it. You will need to find a jquery method for setting the text value of that object.

Comment: I tried code as `$('#sec_currency').val($('#cur_rate :selected').text());`. But it also not workes.